# Send location with message on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sms, location

I am developing an app and would like to attach my location to a message and make this location "clickable" so that they can see it on a map/get a link which opens a map.

I am getting the correct location and store it into `currentPosition` but I am not able to send it so that the user can click on the link/map and see where I am. Is this even possible with the Windows Phone

```
var smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();

var message = Message;
message += string.Format("\r\n My location is\r\n {0}",_currentPosition);
smsComposeTask.Body = message;
smsComposeTask.Show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible because SMS body is plain text. It would depend on the receiver's sms app implementation, whether it recognizes location in sms body or not. For e.g. if you send a phone number or link in plain text in sms, it appears as a clickable number or hyperlink to the receiver only if his/her sms app displays it as such. Also i think wp8's native sms app uses mms to send location and there is no api to send a mms.

Answer (score 1):

you can send it by using a link composer. So when you have found the position you should send it as a link. You can try and look at the app "I'm Here" in the store.